# symfony2 + Propel + FOSUserBundle - Cannot find a query class for MyName\MyBundle\Entity\User

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle, propel

### Reproduce

Add user via `php app/console fos:user:create adminuser --super-admin`; Everything is fine. When i go to myserver.dev/login the login form appears. I type in the created credentials, but the only thing that happens is the message **`Cannot find a query class for MyName\MyBundle\Entity\User`** It seems the redirection goes to the route name is fos_user_security_login; Controller: SecurityController; loginAction(). Do I have to add a redirect after a successful login? Or do I have to extend the User.php Entity with an action?

### That's what I did

I installed symfony 2 and chose Propel since it would make the migration easier. Everything works fine without login functions.

- I added the [FOSUserBundle the setup from](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md).
- Furthermore I replaced the `login.html.twig` to `app/resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Security/login.html.twig`.
- This login form refers to  `action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}`

```
    fos_user:
        db_driver: propel # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
        firewall_name: main
        user_class: MyName\MyBundle\Entity\User
```

```
 The security.yml is as always..
<pre>
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

`php app/console router:debug`results in:

```
     home                              ANY      ANY    ANY  /
     about                             ANY      ANY    ANY  /about
     fos_user_security_login           ANY      ANY    ANY  /login
     fos_user_security_check           POST     ANY    ANY  /login_check
     fos_user_security_logout          ANY      ANY    ANY  /logout
     fos_user_profile_show             GET      ANY    ANY  /profile/
     fos_user_profile_edit             ANY      ANY    ANY  /profile/edit
     fos_user_registration_register    ANY      ANY    ANY  /register/
     fos_user_registration_check_email GET      ANY    ANY  /register/check-email
     fos_user_registration_confirm     GET      ANY    ANY  /register/confirm/{token}
     fos_user_registration_confirmed   GET      ANY    ANY  /register/confirmed
     fos_user_resetting_request        GET      ANY    ANY  /resetting/request
     fos_user_resetting_send_email     POST     ANY    ANY  /resetting/send-email
     fos_user_resetting_check_email    GET      ANY    ANY  /resetting/check-email
     fos_user_resetting_reset          GET|POST ANY    ANY  /resetting/reset/{token}
     fos_user_change_password          GET|POST ANY    ANY  /profile/change-password
```

Comment: Look at step 3. d) on https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md for when you are using Propel - it says you should use FOS\UserBundle\Propel\User instead of what you have here `user_class: MyName\MyBundle\Entity\User`

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Having a similar issue at the moment... :(

Comment: No unfortunatelity not. Symfony was far too huge for my project. I used codeigniter  (https://ellislab.com/codeigniter?) instead. There have to be done some tricks, but now it works fine with a propel integration, twig engine (twiggy) and sparks as package management.